# redefine class name across multiple files

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I have a [Xamarin shared project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/). I find myself writing a lot of usings like this:

```
#if __IOS__
using UIKit;
using NImage = UIKit.UIImage;
using NFont = UIKit.UIFont;
#else
using AppKit;
using NImage = AppKit.NSImage;
using NFont = AppKit.NSFont;
#endif
```

That would be fine, except I have to do it in each file. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it somewhere, for once and for all, to apply across a whole project?